# how to paginate data without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pagination

I have learned pagination from the link
[How to set condition in following code for marking current page in pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690758/how-to-set-condition-in-following-code-for-marking-current-page-in-pagination/43690913#43690913)

using code

```
<?php
    $id=3;  //  test value
    $page=20;   //  test value

    $li=array();    //  temporary array for convenience
    $template='<li%s><a href="?id=%s">%s</a></li>';
    if($id>1) $li[]=sprintf($template,'',$id-1,'Previous');
    for($i=1;$i<=$page;$i++) {
        if($i==$id) $li[]=sprintf($template,' class="active"',$i,$i);   //  Current
        else $li[]=sprintf($template,'',$i,$i);
    }
    if($id<$page) $li[]=sprintf($template,'',$id+1,'Next');
    $li=implode('',$li); // convert to string for printing
?>
<ul class="pagination">
<?php print $li; ?>
</ul>
```

But it is showing data after reloading data? is there any way to make it show without reloading page? I am new to pagination - please help.

Comment: You need to use Ajax for that. When clicking on "next" or "previous", make the call using ajax, get the response and replace the list using javascript.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is correct. Whenever you click on button for the next page, you make an AJAX request that will fetch the data and you can append the new data coming in

Comment: I am not familiar with ajax, I know little jquery and javascript. Can you tell me how I can add ajax with the pagination code above?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ that's the jquery documentation on Ajax. I I would suggest making a JSON array in PHP for the items and retrieve it with Ajax in jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pagination without page load by ajax or jQuery. Please read the example following the link below - 
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html